# How many elements does Bitcoin's secp256k1 have?

Tags: secp256k1

I'm wondering whether it is known how many elements does Bitcoin's elliptic curve have? Have not been able to find an answer to this, only for specific subgroups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over the field *GF(2<sup>256</sup> - 2<sup>32</sup> - 977)*, the equation *y<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>3</sup> + 7* has exactly

115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336

distinct solutions for *(x, y)*, or roughly *2<sup>256</sup> - 1.27077×2<sup>128</sup>*. Together with the point at infinity (which is part of the group, but not the curve), the group size is one more than that. Since that yields a prime number, the group is cyclic (all prime-sized groups are), and only has itself and the trivial group (just the point at infinity) as subgroups.

Comment: Thanks! Must have been looking at subgroups for a different curve.